# Are null and undefined classified as subtypes of other types in typescript?

Tags: angularjs, typescript

I was walking through some old code, where I encountered below snippet :

```
let isNew: boolean = null
let myName: string = undefined
```

The snippet implies that `typescript` allows isNew of type `boolean` to accept `null` and myName of type `string` accept `undefined` ?

***Does this mean that null and undefined are classified as subtypes of other types in `typescript` ?***

Please correct me if I am wrong. Need suggestions and clarity!

Comment: As I know it's under control of setting called strictNullChecks in tsconfig.json. https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html#--strictnullchecks

Answer (score 0):

You can verify this in a javascript console by typing `typeof(null)` and `typeof(undefined)` - TypeScript doesn't treat them differently, because ultimately your TypeScript code gets converted to javascript.

`null` is a type of `object`, and `undefined` is a type of `undefined` (ie. it is a "type" itself).

`undefined` is the value given to any declared variable in javascript that has not been assigned a value. `null` is a value purposely given to a variable, although you can also purposely set a variable to `undefined` as well.

The two lines you posted would produce errors on most configurations of the TypeScript compiler, depending on the tsconfig.json file. If you want to declare a variable in TypeScript of type `T` that can be set to `null` or `undefined`, where `T` is any other type (eg. `boolean`, `string`), then you must declare the variable appropriately, eg `T|null` or `T|undefined`. For example:

```
let isNew1: boolean = null; // error
let isNew2: boolean|null = null; // ok
let isNew3: boolean|null; // error, can't assign undefined

let myName1: string = undefined; // error
let myName2: string|undefined = undefined; // ok
let myName3: string|undefined; // ok
```

Note you can also declare variables that allow undefined in types and interfaces using the `?` symbol (eg. `myVariable?: string`).

Comment: The lines which I posted works just fine, with no errors. That's the concern. So, It means that null and undefined are kind of subtype of other types line boolean, number etc.

Comment: The lines you posted work fine *with your current tsconfig.json* but that doesn't make your assertion correct - that null or undefined are subtypes of boolean, number. I just explained what they are in my answer. If those lines work fine then I would argue your tsconfig.json is set up incorrectly, because you're able to defy the typing given to those two variables, which defeats the purpose of TypeScript. You may as well just write your app in javascript because if your code works with your current tsconfig.json then you gain literally nothing from it being written TypeScript.